# Using some sort of "Contains()" function in ActionScript 2

Tags: flash, actionscript, contains

Is there any way to parse a string looking at it with some sort of "contains" function in actionscript 2 ? I tried searching for this online but I can't find anything.

I'm using a form that has a input for an email, and I wanted to check if that email contain's "@" and ".com" to c heck if its valid.

Here is a fictional example of what I wanted to accomplish:

```
if( emailInput.text.contains ( "@" ) ) {
  trace("Ok");
} else {
  trace("Not ok");
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `indexOf("@")` which will return the index of the string or else -1 if it can't find it.

More info: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001551.html

Comment: That works quite nicelly. When I said "contains()", I was thinking about Director's Lingo programing, but now that I actually look at it, the javascript context is also called "indexOf()". 

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Director/11.5/UsingScripting/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811d64c1a1b3-7948.html

Anyway, thanks.